# Java: Pattern behaves differently in Scanner

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Came across a strange behavior of regex matching in Java. The first output command prints `true` as expected, but when the same string is packed into `Scanner`, the output is `false`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" *\\[");
  System.out.println(p.asPredicate().test("[]")); //true

  Scanner s = new Scanner("[]");
  System.out.println(s.hasNext(" *\\[")); //false
}
```

Comment: Try with `s.hasNext(p)`

Comment: @horcrux From javadoc: *An invocation of this method of the form <tt>hasNext(pattern)</tt>
     * behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
     * <tt>hasNext(Pattern.compile(pattern))</tt>.*

Comment: @SpaceTrucker You're right. So the point is that `Pattern.compile(myRegex)p.asPredicate().test(myString)` searches for an occurrence of `myRegex` in `myString`, while `new Scanner(myString).hasNext(myRegex)` checks if the whole content of `myString` is matched by `myRegex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `public boolean hasNext(String pattern)` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.lang.String-):

> Returns true if the next token matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

Here next token is `[]` not just `[` (since delimiter is one or more whitespace) but `" *\\["` pattern doesn't match that token *entirely* (`]` is not matched) so you are informed about it by result `false`.

If you want to check if token starts with `[` you can add `.*` at the end of your pattern to let it match rest of token. You can also remove `*` since whitespace is default delimiter so it can't be part of token.

---

In case of

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" *\\[");
System.out.println(p.asPredicate().test("a[]")); //true
```

If you take a look at code of `asPredicate` you will see it is implemented as:

```
public Predicate<String> asPredicate() {
    return s -> matcher(s).find();
}
```

`find()` method doesn't check if whole string matches pattern, but tries to find even part of it which matches pattern. Since `[]` contains zero or more spaces followed by `[` you are seeing `true` as result.

Comment: I see. Is there a possibility to check the start of a token, or I should add `.*` in the end of every regex?

Comment: Here simplest way would be adding `.*` at the end. But depending on what you really want to achieve maybe it is better to avoid Scanner and use Pattern directly? It is hard to tell without knowing what you really want to achieve.

Comment: I'm parsing the string, containing a JSON-like array, so I need both direct access to characters and an easy way to parse whole int or float. Is there any alternative to Scanner in this situation. Using JSON parser is not an option, this case cannot be handled generically.

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov I can't tell much without seeing real data and expected results. Since this question already has few answers about currently described problem you it wouldn't be good to modify it because it would invalidate posted answers. So if you wish to ask about your specific case consider creating separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As per [`Predicate.test`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-) description from Javadoc:

. true if the input argument matches the predicate, otherwise false

What is not written explicitly in Javadoc but implied is that `test(T t)` method doesn't match like `String.matches(String)` method, where start and end anchors are implicit. `test` method on the other hand doesn't match complete string and you will need to use anchors in your regex to make it behave like `String.matches` or `Scanner.hasNext(Pattern )` methods.

Following code will give consistent `false` result from both the calls

```
final String input = "[]";
final String re = "^ *\\[$"; // note use of anchors in the regex
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);

System.out.println(p.asPredicate().test(input)); // false

Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
System.out.println(s.hasNext(p)); //false
s.close();
```